# Cómo puedo combinar tk y turtle?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, python-turtle

La cosa es que quiero crear un pequeño programita muy corto en el que un `turtle` se mueva, pero me he encontrado con algunos problemas a la hora de ponerlo dentro de un `tk`.

Quiero hacer que un `turtle` tenga una forma de un gif que ya tengo, y poder moverlo en la pantalla con unos botones que pondré fuera del `turtle`, pero dentro del `tk`.
Descubrí que lo mejor es meterlo dentro de un canvas y usar `RawTurtle` pero me ha generado problemas.
El `tk` tiene una imagen de fondo, y quiero que el `turtle` tenga una imagen de fondo también, pero no sé como ponerlo todo y me sale mal porque la imagen del `tk` la pongo dentro de un `label`, pero las dos imágenes (de fondo del canvas y del `turtle`) no me aparecen y me sale todo en blanco :(

(Los botones y los comandos para mover el turtle ya me los sé, por ahora sólo me falta aprender a crear muros jajaj, pero ya lo iré descubriendo)
Muchas gracias por su tiempo :)

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bosque")
root.geometry('900x800')
root.resizable(0,0)

image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Sin título-1.gif.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
lab=tk.Label(image=image)
lab.pack()
lab.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)

canvas = turtle.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
canvas.place(x=59, y=184)

imagen=tk.PhotoImage(file="Sin título-1.gif - copia.gif")
self.canvas.create_image(30, 100, image=imagen, anchor="nw")


c = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: En primer lugar este sitio no es para pedir recomendaciones (por lo que dices al inicio), el resto de tu pregunta esta bien

Comment: Oh no sabía perdón

Comment: tranquilo, solo borra esa parte, por que puede que recibas votos negativos. En cuanto a tu pregunta te ayudaría si supiera de `TK` y `turtle` :(

Comment: lo siento, procederé a editar tu pregunta.